# Java Rest client API using Future

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous

I need to develop a client Rest API in Java, that uses a library with asynchronous http. More concretely, I can make Rest CRUD operations, that return a Future of the http Response. My question is, how should my wrapper API deal with these Future objects? Should I just provide the user of the API the Future and it is up to him to deal with it, or should I develop some threading mechanism?

Comment: What Http Client are you using?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO if I was the consumer of your API I would rather you did not do my multithreading unless:

- You have your own specialized highly optimized Event IO loop using NIO or something (aka Netty/Grizzle) (e.g. https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client).
- Have a way I can plug in my own [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

What I'm saying is I don't thing you will add any value by returning Future's and in fact is annoying if I want to handle the threading myself but all you offer is the async API (returning `Future`).

Now making your API client [Threadsafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) is preferred and does interest me (that is I don't want to have to instantiate a new client everytime I use it).

**However** if you are using something like [async-http-client (NIO)](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client) then hell yeah return the `Future`.

Comment: so you mean that it is OK if my API REST methods return all a  Future<BusinessObject>?

Comment: Read my edit. Yes so long as your using something that truly is NIO.

Answer (score 0):

Why it is required ? - I feel it is important to have it as Future for high load systems.

- As a API, it will be helpful to have such a functionality because you don't who the consumers are.
- For a web site, if it needs to support high loads, it will be waste of cpu time just to wait on http response. Rather making it a async, makes the http worker more efficient to handle other requests.
- Use library which can simplify this for you.